# kitchen synced_folders owner and group

Tags: vagrant, test-kitchen

I am trying to spin a chef cookbook with kitchen converge. I have synced_folders set up which are created correctly, however I can not assign the desired USER:GROUP. There is no kitchen documentation on how to do it and I have tried different ways which either generates error or gets ignored. 
I have been able to do so without any issue on Vagrantfile and this is the way it is handles on Vagrant:

```
myvm.vm.synced_folder "~/Workspace/test", "/opt/apps/test/synced", owner: "www", group: "www"
```

here is how I have tried to achieve the same thing using kitchen but as I stated it only creates the folder with default user(vagrant)

```
suites:
  - name: myvm
    driver:
      vm_hostname: myvm.kitchen.verifi
      network:
        - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.50.14"}]
      synced_folders:
        - ["~/Workspace/test", "/opt/apps/test/synced", "create: true", "owner: www-data", "group: www-data"]
```

the above only creates the folder
changing it to :

```
  synced_folders:
    - ["~/Workspace/test", "/opt/apps/test/synced", "create: true", "owner: www-data group: www-data"]
```

was basically the same, the owner and groups get ignored

changing it to :

```
  synced_folders:
    - ["~/Workspace/test", "/opt/apps/test/synced", "create: true owner: www-data group: www-data"]
```

generates error.
No matter what combinations I use it does not succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at [Vagrant doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html), I think you should put commas inside a third element of the array and user/group should be in quotes. Try;

```
synced_folders:
  - ["~/Workspace/test", "/opt/apps/test/synced", 'create: true, owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"']
```

[Whole third parameter should be put directly in Vagrantfile as-is](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/4152db8f8ee098350994f23892a75092cccf2d13/templates/Vagrantfile.erb#L75).

Comment: Thank you, this syntax is working. the difference I see is having the whole thing inside a single code and only double coding the user and permission part.